# ASP.Net C# - Concatenating a variable to access controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, web-controls

My original function is below, however, I'd like to modify this so that I can pass in a number to update the necessary controls e.g. getQuestionDetails(3) would update lblQuestion3.Text and lblQuestion3Type.Text.

However, my attempt at this only seems to work when I execute getQuestionDetails(1), getQuestionDetails(2), getQuestionDetails(3) in that order.  If I try to execute getQuestionDetails(3) first, nothing happens.  Any ideas why?

original code:

```
protected void getQuestionDetails()
{
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
    MySqlDataReader reader;

    string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE question_id=@QuestionID";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@QuestionID", MySqlDbType.Int32);
    cmd.Parameters["@QuestionID"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(ddlQuestion1IDs.SelectedValue);

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            lblQuestion1.Text = reader["question"].ToString();

            if (reader["type"].ToString().Equals("T"))
            {
                lblQuestion1Type.Text = "simple question - one word answer";
            }
            else if (reader["type"].ToString().Equals("R"))
            {
                lblQuestion1Type.Text = "multiple choice - one correct answer";
            }
            else if (reader["type"].ToString().Equals("C"))
            {
                lblQuestion1Type.Text = "multiple choice - more than one correct answer";
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        lblError.Text = "Database connection error - failed to get question details.";
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

my attempt:

```
protected void getQuestionDetails(string a)
{
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
    MySqlDataReader reader;

    string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE question_id=@QuestionID";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@QuestionID", MySqlDbType.Int32);
    cmd.Parameters["@QuestionID"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(((DropDownList)this.FindControl("ddlQuestion" + a + "IDs")).SelectedValue);

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            ((Label)this.FindControl("lblQuestion" + a)).Text = reader["question"].ToString();

            if (reader["type"].ToString().Equals("T"))
            {
                ((Label)this.FindControl("lblQuestion" + a + "Type")).Text = "simple question - one word answer";
            }
            else if (reader["type"].ToString().Equals("R"))
            {
                ((Label)this.FindControl("lblQuestion" + a + "Type")).Text = "multiple choice - one correct answer";
            }
            else if (reader["type"].ToString().Equals("C"))
            {
                ((Label)this.FindControl("lblQuestion" + a + "Type")).Text = "multiple choice - more than one correct answer";
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        lblError.Text = "Database connection error - failed to get question details.";
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you put all your lblQuestionType .. in a single array ?

Comment: Why don't you pass `a` as a `string`? instead of calling `.ToString()` everywhere?  Have you stepped through the code to see what's happening? Do you have controls *ddlQuestion1IDs*, *ddlQuestion2IDs*, *ddlQuestion3IDs* etc

Comment: @christiandev I've modified the code. I do. I've update the original post to describe the issue further. getQuestionDetails(3) only works after running getQuestionDetails(1) and getQuestionDetails(2).

Comment: Do you change the dropdown's for each time you invoke the `getQuestionDetails` method? **side note:** You should use *CamelCase* in `C#`, so `GetQuestionDetails` is more relevant :)

Comment: Not directly solving your problem, but you can use a Dictionary<string, string> to link your possible values reader["type"] can have so you don't need to use 3 ifs. Also, use string.Format() to generate your control names, because it is more readable. And PLEASE don't use single letter variable names, it only makes your code harder to read. Also, select * from Questions makes me cringe, please don't do that. Only select the columns you are going to need, because it speeds up your code.

Comment: @christiandev What do you mean by do I change the dropdowns?  I intend to invoke getQuestionDetails(1) within the ddlQuestion1IDs_SelectedIndexChanged event, getQuestionDetails(2) within the ddlQuestion2IDs_SelectedIndexChanged event, getQuestionDetails(3) within the ddlQuestion3IDs_SelectedIndexChanged event...

Comment: Also, isn't GetQuestionDetails PascalCase? :s

Comment: PascalCase, CamelCase...basically, the **G** should be caps :)